# How can I find out what JAR file a certain class belongs to?

Tags: java, class, jar

I am looking to find out what JAR file a certain class is contained in. Thank you!

Comment: You need to give more details, is this a library class or a third party class? etc. A jar file is just a zip file so you can open and see what .class files are contained.. But the reverse is harder with such a vague question

Comment: Ah sorry, it's a just a class I made in my code, I am trying to make a batch script using it but I need to put the jar file in the directory of the batch script and I just don't know which one contains the class.

Comment: Its been a while since my java days but I believe that eclipse compiles all classes in a project into a single jar, so you just need to use the jar named after the project

Answer (score 1):

Look at [JarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/). This will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

- [Class Locator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classlocator/) an eclipse plugin which may help you, if you are using eclipse.
- [FindJar.com](http://www.findjar.com/class/activation/Locator.html) to find it from internet.
- Also [Jboss tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse you can use ctrl+shift+t which is search for targets. You have to give class name and it will show you jars related to it. Also not that these jars should be attach with build paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you need location of a class in runtime - you can try following:

```
obj.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

But be aware that `getCodeSource` can return `null` for some classes, e.g. for classes from `rt.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

If your using eclipse just press F3 taste and you'll see the jar information at the top in the opening window

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

[find the jar file given a class name](http://sacharya.com/find-the-jar-file-given-a-class-name/)

[How do I check which Jar file a class file belong to?](https://developer.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2031766)